# How to combine colums which contain bit-wise data?

Tags: python, dataframe, concatenation

[screenshot of dataframe data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXtNR.jpg)

I have a list of data fed into a dataframe in python. I require to combine these columns into a single one creating a 3 bit column.

```
df['combined']=df['A'].astype(str)+df['B'].astype(str)+df['C'].astype(str)
```

The following code was used but did not return a muxed bit output

Comment: what do you mean by muxed bit output?

Comment: Like 000,001,011,100,101,110,111

Comment: what kind of output are you getting?

Comment: i am getting 0,1,11,100,110,111 respectively

Comment: that is weird. There is no reason for it to output like that. Do you have missing values?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem. The formula works perfectly fine with the given data

Comment: Make sure you are *not* doing `.astype(int)` or some other numeric transformation after the code line you show us.